# Sagepay Test Environment apparent limitations

Tags: testing, opayo

I am currently working on integrating Sagepay with a financial payment system.  We have a Sagepay test account and have been creating transactions within the Sagepay test environment fine.
However, we have a number of test plan scenarios that don't appear to be supported with the Sagepay test environment, e.g.
Create a card payment successfully then do a Repeat against the payment and simulate a failure at Repeat stage (insufficient funds, card expired, etc).
Sagepay support have said this is NOT testable so how is anyone testing their Sagepay integrations? Are there third party test environments available or what is anyone doing to test their Sagepay integrated systems?

Answer (score 0):

Just a suggestion.

Create a PAYMENT transaction.
Block the IP address that the transactions are initiated from (in My Sage Pay)
Try a REPEAT transaction call to the API.

It won't simulate the card expiry / failure to auth scenario, but might help. If you do try, be aware that the setting might not take immediate effect (should be around 15 minutes or so).

Comment: Hi Rik,
Thanks for taking the trouble to respond but I don't think that's going to help as all that will test is the application's response to a denied server rather than the application's response to a denied REPEAT. 
Steve